# Add html elements based on number of JSON keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on a piece of code in which I want to generate `span` and `textarea` elements based on the number of JSON key:value pairs.

This is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPropertyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Property</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" id="newProperty"  name="newProperty" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    **<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Value</span>
                        <textarea id="newValue" name="newValue" class="form-control" placeholder="value" style="resize:vertical;" ></textarea>
                    </div>**
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" id="savePropertyBtn" name="action" value="Save Property" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="updatePropertyBtn" name="action" value="Update Property" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script which loads the `newValue` is this:

```
$(".href-select").click(function() {
    var propName = $(this).text();
    var propVal = $(this).attr('itemprop');
    var json = JSON.parse(propVal, 'UTF-8');
    var count = 0;
    for (i in json) {
        console.log(json[i]);
        count++;
    }
    console.log(count);
    $("#newProperty").attr('readonly', true);
    $("#newProperty").val(propName);
    $("#newValue").val(propVal);
    $("#savePropertyBtn").hide();
    $("#updatePropertyBtn").
});
```

I have modded the script to get the individual values from the JSON.

**My idea is :** to increment the `count` as I read the JSON values and then use this to add `count` number of `span` & `textarea` elements in the html through iteration. Also I want to add the count in the html and hide it so that I can get the count in the `request` object as well ( I will be creating a map with the number of values ).

Please help me in achieving my idea.

**EDIT :** This is what is expected if the JSON contains two pairs.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Value</span>
    <textarea id="newValue" name="newValue" class="form-control" placeholder="value" style="resize:vertical;" ></textarea>
    <span class="input-group-addon">Value</span>
    <textarea id="newValue" name="newValue" class="form-control" placeholder="value" style="resize:vertical;" ></textarea>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**  This is how the dialog box looks right now :
[image: dialog box]

The value textbox contains the JSON. Now I want the textbox to look like this:

```
Name: [test222]
Host: [DS01ATA]
Port: [   22  ]
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have an idea of how to do this, so why don't you try it? Then, if you have some specific question/problem, come back here and ask.

Comment: instead of first counting and then adding count elements, add teh elements in your counting loop.

Comment: One warning: make sure you don't use the same ID in all the textareas you are generating. If you need them to have a common identifier, use a class instead. HTML IDs must be unique.

Comment: @forgivenson I know what I want to do , but I don't know how to do it. I am very new to jQuery.

Comment: @bwright that is what I want to know. I can't figure out how to add it .

Comment: let me google that for you http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Check out the documentation for the `append` function. http://api.jquery.com/append/ For future reference, I just googled "jquery add html element" and that was the first result. Google is your friend.

Comment: @bwright I saw the docs. The html part which I have shown above is just one part of a div class. I just want to know how to add this to this particular div class. Also how can I send the count to the html.

Comment: You have to get the div first, then call the append function on it. For example, if you did `$(".input-group"), that would give you a list of all html elements with a class of "input-group" (notice the period before the class name in the selector). Remember, classes aren't guaranteed unique, so my example is only unique if you only use that class once.

Comment: @forgiveson that exactly is the problem. I have a lot of elements which use the same class.

Comment: @forgiveson can I reference the div using an id or name ?

Comment: Assuming your `JSON` has 2 `key:value` pairs, post the expected output/HTML.

Comment: @lshettyl I've edited the question with the expected html for 2 pair JSON..

Comment: Is `newValue == json[i]` ? Also, `ID` needs to be unique. How do you like the IDs to be added `newValue + i` ?

Comment: @lshettyl yes . `newValue = json[i]` and that id is fine for me. I just want to get the same in  my request object too. Also I want the `count` of objects so I can get a `i` value for iterations when adding to the map.

Comment: @lshettyl I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: You've kept confusing all of us!!! all you want is to convert a JSON object to readable text which is what it is in the last screen grab in your question?

Comment: How exactly have I confused you ?? I have been giving every bit of detail I can ..

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the `div` first, then call the `append` function on it. For example, if you did `$(".input-group")`, that would give you a list of all html elements with a class of `input-group` (notice the period before the class name in the selector). Remember, classes aren't guaranteed unique, so my example is only unique if you only use that class once. Once you have the desired element, you can manipulate that element. In this case, you want to add an HTML element to the `div`.

```
$(".input-group").append("<span>Sample html string</span>");
```

References:

- Docs for append: http://api.jquery.com/append/
- CSS selector "playground" (with documentation): http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/

Comment: I have more than one div which uses the same class. Can I refer the div using an id or name ?

Comment: Yup. Check out the second link I included in my answer. It has a TON of different options you have when using selectors. If you want to learn jQuery, you really need to learn CSS selectors.

Comment: yes I can add using the id :) but the problem is , this keeps appending everytime the js is called .

Comment: Of course it will append each time you call it. What are you expecting it to do? If you want it to check if the element you are adding already exists, you need to write code to check that.

Comment: There is a list of items which on clicking opens a dialog box. And in that dialog box , this is one of the div tags. But this keeps appending everytime I click on an elemnt.

Comment: That doesn't clarify it at all. If you want more help, you need to show all the relevant code, preferably in a jsfiddle.

Comment: I've edited the question which contains the html block for the dialog box. JSFiddle wont work out as this is a very small part of the whole html file. Please let me know if you have any more queries.

Answer (score 1):

To copy - paste a `div` using `jQuery`

```
function copyDiv(divId) {
    var content = $(divId).html();
    var newdiv = $('<div>');
    newdiv.html(content);
    $(divId).after(newdiv);
    return newdiv;
}
```

Calling `copyDiv('#mydiv')` will create a div with same content below `#mydiv`.

jQuery [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) may also be useful here.

For your case, this function can be called inside your loop

```
for (i in json) {
    var newdiv = copyDiv('#form-div-id');
    ...    // add values to new div like 'i' and json[i]
}
```

Comment: I think this will work out.. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: @ViChU Okay, perhaps you can accept and upvote the answer if it works out.